# How to speed up access to Oracle table after deleting millions of rows?

Tags: oracle

I'm newbie to Oracle and database staff.

I had a huge Oracle 11g table of data with 200 million rows. I delete them all and kept only one. I read many articles on how to recover table space after deleting rows, etc but my table still takes a long time to be accessed (minutes).

Example:

`select * from MyTable;` Takes 0.02 seconds to return one record which is ok !

`select * from MyTable where ID > 0;` Takes more than 20 minutes to return one record.

(The ID field has an index)

I have successfully run the following commands:

`alter table MyTable enable row movement;`

`alter table MyTable shrink space compact;`

`alter table MyTable deallocate unused;`

But I still have the same issue.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Did you update your table statistics?

Comment: How can I do this please ?

Comment: If you only wanted to keep one row, why not copy the one row to another table (e.g. using `CREATE TABLE mytable_temp AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ....`), then `TRUNCATE mytable`, then copy the one row back? `TRUNCATE` will reclaim all of the space previously used by the table.

Comment: Another thing to try is to rebuild the index on your `ID` column.

Comment: did you run `dbms_stats.analyze_table()`?

Comment: Thank you all. I run the command EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('Schema', 'Table'); which solved my issue :) !